# Have `oc` follow a cluster depending on directory

Tags: openshift, cluster-computing

I use the `oc` tool for several different clusters.

Since I am usually keeping local yaml files for any OpenShift objects I view/modify, either ad hoc or due to some config management scheme of the individual cluster, I have a separate directory on my machine for each cluster (which, in turn, is of coursed versioned in git). Let's call them `~/clusters/a/`, `~/clusters/b/` etc.

Now. When I `cd` around on my local machine, the `oc` command uses the global `~/.kube/config` to find the cluster I logged in last, to. Or in other words, `oc` does not care at all about which directory I am in.

Is there a way to have `oc` store a "local" configuration (i.e. in `~/clusters/a/.kube_config` or something like that), so that when I enter the `~/clusters/a/` directory, I am automatically working with that cluster without having to explicitely switch clusters with `oc login`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Graham's answer, `KUBECONFIG` can specify a list of config files which will be merged if more than one exist. The first to set a particular value wins, as described in the [merging rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files).

So you can add a local config with just the `current-context`, e.g. `~/clusters/a/.kube_config` could be

```
current-context: projecta/192-168-99-100:8443/developer
```

and `~/clusters/b/.kube_config`:

```
current-context: projectb/192-168-99-101:8443/developer
```

Obviously need to adjust this for your particular cluster using the format

```
current-context: <namespace>/<cluster>/<user>
```

Then set `KUBECONFIG` with a relative path and the global config

```
export KUBECONFIG=./.kube_config:~/.kube/config
```

Note that if `./.kube_config` does not exist it will be ignored.

The `current-content` will then be overridden by the one defined in the local .kube_config, if one exists.

I tested this locally with 2 minishift clusters and it seemed to work ok. Have not tested what the behaviour is when setting config though.

Comment: Nice. One could even write a small shell script which travels up until it hits a `./kube_config`...

Comment: Well, I was thinking that you could set `KUBECONFIG` in your `.bashrc` file (or equivalent) then no script is required. If you are in a directory with a `.kube_config` then `oc` will use it.

Comment: I think I see your point though. If you are in some sub-directory e.g. `~/clusters/a/1`, then the `.kube_config` in `~/clusters/a` is no longer visible so scripting it in that case would be useful.

Comment: `s/script/alias/` in my comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to specify different directories for configuration for each cluster. You would need to set the environment variable to respective directories in each separate terminal session window.

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable